# Unable to publish wsdl file

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services

Can any one tell me how to public the wsdl file ie., that web service is created in java using eclipse.I am self learner to java/eclipse and web service too,so can any one please make me clear with steps.

Thanks for your time!...

Comment: What appplication server are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache Axis has some cool tools that I frequently use - to generate a wsdl, use [java2wsdl](http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#Java2WSDLBuildingWSDLFromJava).  It has a command line version, but also a Maven plugin (which I highly recommend) that will re-generate the wsdl for you automatically each time you package your web service.

What's more, the axis stuff also provides auto-generation of client stubs by which you can use your web service in consumer apps or services.  Alternatively, [JAX-WS tools](http://jax-ws.java.net/jax-ws-21-ea1/docs/jaxws-tools.html) can be used for this as well.  In either case I would recommend automating the process with Maven.

If you package your wsdl with your app in this way (rather than letting a server do this for you automatically), you can be certain that your contract will look the same on any platform.